# What is happening inside of my printFun function that is causing this behaviour

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to figure out recursion and how it operates and I cant seem to figure out what is happening in this code.

```
def printFun(test):
 
    if (test < 1):
        return
    else:
 
        print(test, end="a ")        
        printFun(test-1)  # statement 2
        print(test, end="n ")
        return
 
# Driver Code
test = 3
printFun(test)
```

This outputs

```
3a 2a 1a 1n 2n 3n
```

I can make sense of the first 4 outputs.
test = 3, which not less than 1, so print test(1a), then re-call the printFun function with test-1
being 2, which is not less than 1, so print test (2a), then (1a) then 0, which IS less than 1
so return. I assume this brings you back to the

```
print(test, end='n')
```

line? which now prints 1n.

This is where I am left perplexed... what is happening beyond this??? How does it start ascending and then stop again at 3? What is the flow and logic of this?
Sorry if this is a ridiculous question and I am overlooking something blatantly obvious.

But I cannot wrap my mind around this...
Anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Just like any other function, each caller waits for its recursive child call to finish, then does whatever is _after_ the recursive call when it returns control back to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Its because the stack unwinds depth first. In pseudocode, with each indentation being a new call to the function, you get

```
call printFun(3)
    print 3a
    call printFun(2)
        print 2a
        call printFun(1)
            print 1a
            call printFun(0)
                print nothing
                return
            (test still = 1 in this frame)
            print 1n
            return
        (test still = 2 in this frame)
        print 2n
        return
    (test still = 3 in this frame)
    print 3n
    return
```

When you return from the most recently called `printFun`, you get back to an older set of local variables holding the older value.

Comment: Very interesting, I will have to ponder this, it makes a decent amount of sense. not the behavior I would have anticipated, it makes sense looking at it in that perspective. I certainly never would have drawn that conclusion that the code I posted would have ever behaved in that manor. I guess something I have to approach from a hard stance rule of how it unwinds and not how it logically plays out using my brain as the compiler haha. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: taking the pseudocode approach logic you gave,
Its almost like it is appending each instance of 'test' to a list. until it meets the base condition.. and then  printing the test[] in reverse with 'b', is how I would have imagined i would have gotten that behavior? 
Perhaps I overcomplicated this one a bit haha.

Comment: This is a case where grabbing a pencil and paper, then going through the steps, can really help. Make each call to the function a box with `test = whatever` in it. Then draw an arrow on each call til you've reached your end condition. Now, you trace those arrows backward in order.

Comment: Its making a stack, which is much like a list. lifo (last in, first out) - meaning when you call the function, ils like appended a new frame holding the new function's local variables on the end of the list, and when you return its like popping the last value to get back to the previous.

Comment: Yeah again the first part makes sense, but why does it then turn and go backwards? I cant pick up on any code that would constitute that behavior, no test+1 until test = 3, so to speak..
The output makes sense given that logic, but why is that the logic being implemented? Is this one of those 'its just the way it goes' things? 
Appreciate you walking me through this!

Comment: Oh, Okay yes that makes sense now, I remember learning about that briefly a while back. I believe I have it understood haha

Thank you!

Comment: Its because functions have to return to the same place they were called. When in the function with test=3, you call the function with test=2. Now, when that function finally gets around to printing "n2", it returns to ... that instance of the function where test=3.

Answer (score 0):

You call `printFun` three times and each of it prints twice, so we should have 6 prints, isn't it?

Sometimes it's hard to unsolve recursion but it doesn't differ as calling another function:

```
def foo():
  print("before")
  other_foo()
  print("after")
```

Do you agree everything that is printed by `other_foo` will be between "before" and "after"? It's the same case, you could write it that way:

```
def printFun1():
    print("1a")
    print("1n")


def printFun2():
    print("2a")
    printFun1() # it prints "1a" and "1n" between "2a" and "2n"
    print("2n")


def printFun3():
    print("3a")
    printFun2()
    print("3n")

printFun3()
```